# MitreID Server with Drupal 7 User Database

Tags: postgresql, drupal, drupal-7, openid-connect

I am trying to configure a MitreID Connect based IdP with users in an existing Drupal 7 user database. I have integrated the Drupal DB with other services before, but I am new to using MitreID Connect.

I have so far not been able to find any examples; I am curious if anyone has already done that and could point me in the right direction (e.g. adding Drupal 7 hashing algorithm; assigning roles to users; etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up creating database views that map the Drupal database into the standard MitreID database structure, so that all existing queries work.

Then we ended up using the MitreID Overlay project. The only thing left to do was to write a custom PasswordEncoder class that handles the Drupal 7 specific functionality (Drupal 7 hashing algorithm). This class then gets used as standard password handler.